# Xubuntu 19.10 - Black screen with mouse pointer

Tags: xubuntu, 19.10

Xubuntu 19.10 on Dell Optiplex 755 - works perfectly.

Only issue is when I leave the pc unattended for some time, I find that there is only a black screen with the mouse pointer visible. Otherwise there is nothing on the screen.

I am able to ctrl-alt-f1 and login via terminal and reboot and everything then resumes normally.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The same situation with MSI VR600X.

It's helpful to me: https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/

Temporary Fix

To get the system to boot:

```
After turning on your PC, hold the right SHIFT key to get to the GRUB bootloader.
Once GRUB is open, press the “e” key to edit the first highlighted entry “Ubuntu”.
Move your cursor down to the line that starts with “linux”, and use the right arrow key to find the section with the words “ro quiet splash”.
Add “nomodeset” after these words.

nomodeset

Feel free to remove “quiet” and “splash” for more verbosity to troubleshoot the boot process.
Press “CTRL + X” or “F10” to boot.
The system should now boot.
```

Permanent Fix

To permanently resolve the issue:

```
Once the system has booted using the temporary fix, log in.
Open a terminal window (Applications -> Terminal, or press the “Start” button and type terminal).
Either “su” in to root, or use “sudo” to open your favorite text editor and edit the file “/etc/default/grub” (I use nano which can be install by running “dnf install nano”):

nano /etc/default/grub

Locate the line with the variable “GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT”, and add “nomodeset” to the variables. Feel free to remove “splash” and “quiet” if you’d like text boot. Here’s an example of my line after editing (yours will look different):

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

Save the file and exit the text editor (CTRL+X to quit, the press “y” and enter to save).
At the bash prompt, execute the following command to regenerate the grub.conf file on the /boot partition from your new default file:

update-grub

Restart your system, it should now boot!
```

Please Note: Always make sure you have a full system backup before modifying any system files!